# Optimization 8-puzzle

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I'm junior programmer, I am trying to solve 8-puzzle problem with breadth first search, but it took too long time to solve it, i want to optimize my code. 
Configuration: `[[5, 4, 3], [0, 7, 2], [6, 1, 8]]` is going to solve in `22.623718615` seconds,
configuration `[[8, 0, 6], [5, 4, 7], [2, 3, 1]]` took among `235.721346421` seconds.
I want to decrease solve time.
There is my code:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from collections import deque
from time import perf_counter

most_hard = [[8, 0, 6], [5, 4, 7], [2, 3, 1]]  # 30 moves


class CheckPuzzle:
    def __init__(self, puzzle: list):
        self.puzzle = puzzle
        self.len = len(puzzle)
        if self.len == 3:
            self.goal = [[1, 2, 3],
                         [4, 5, 6],
                         [7, 8, 0]]
        elif self.len == 4:
            self.goal = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
                         [5, 6, 7, 8],
                         [9, 10, 11, 12],
                         [13, 14, 15, 0]]
        if not self.is_valid():
            raise TypeError("Puzzle is not valid")
        elif not self.is_solvable():
            raise Exception("Unsolvable puzzle")

    #  создай ф-ию check

    def sum_of_numbers(self) -> int:
        return sum(self.convert_to_1d(self.goal))

    def sum_of_squares(self) -> int:
        return sum([i ** 2 for i in self.convert_to_1d(self.goal)])

    def is_valid(self) -> bool:
        sum_of_numbers = 0
        sum_of_squares = 0
        for row in range(self.len):
            for column in range(self.len):
                sum_of_numbers += self.puzzle[row][column]
                sum_of_squares += (self.puzzle[row][column]) ** 2
        return sum_of_numbers == self.sum_of_numbers() and sum_of_squares == self.sum_of_squares()

    def convert_to_1d(self, board) -> list:
        one_dimension_matrix = []
        for row in range(self.len):
            for column in range(self.len):
                one_dimension_matrix.append(board[row][column])
        return one_dimension_matrix

    def inversion(self, board) -> int:
        inversion = 0
        one_dimension_matrix = self.convert_to_1d(board)
        for index in range(len(one_dimension_matrix)):
            temp = one_dimension_matrix[index]
            if temp == 0 or temp == 1:
                continue
            for elem in one_dimension_matrix[index:]:
                if elem == 0:
                    continue
                if temp > elem:
                    inversion += 1
        return inversion

    def is_solvable(self) -> bool:
        inv_of_matrix = self.inversion(self.puzzle)
        inv_of_goal_matrix = self.inversion(self.goal)
        return (inv_of_matrix % 2 == 0 and inv_of_goal_matrix % 2 == 0) or \
               (inv_of_matrix % 2 == 1 and inv_of_goal_matrix % 2 == 1)


class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, board: list):
        self.board = board
        self.len = len(board)
        if self.len == 3:
            self.goal = [[1, 2, 3],
                         [4, 5, 6],
                         [7, 8, 0]]
        elif self.len == 4:
            self.goal = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
                         [5, 6, 7, 8],
                         [9, 10, 11, 12],
                         [13, 14, 15, 0]]

    def print_matrix(self) -> str:
        output = ''
        for row in self.board:
            for elem in row:
                output += str(elem) + " "
            output += '\n'
        return output

    def get_index(self, matrix, value) -> tuple:
        for i in range(self.len):
            for j in range(self.len):
                if matrix[i][j] == value:
                    return i, j

    def manhattan(self):
        distance = 0
        for i in range(self.len):
            for j in range(self.len):
                if self.board[i][j] != 0:
                    x, y = divmod(self.board[i][j] - 1, self.len)
                    distance += abs(x - i) + abs(y - j)
        return distance

    def list_of_possible_moves(self) -> list:
        x, y = self.get_index(self.board, 0)
        possible_moves = []
        if x > 0:
            possible_moves.append((x - 1, y))
        if x < self.len - 1:
            possible_moves.append((x + 1, y))
        if y > 0:
            possible_moves.append((x, y - 1))
        if y < self.len - 1:
            possible_moves.append((x, y + 1))
        return possible_moves

    def move(self, to: tuple) -> list:
        moving_board = deepcopy(self.board)
        x, y = self.get_index(self.board, 0)
        i, j = to
        moving_board[x][y], moving_board[i][j] = moving_board[i][j], moving_board[x][y]
        return moving_board

    def solved(self) -> bool:
        return self.board == self.goal

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ''.join(map(str, self))

    def __iter__(self):
        for row in self.board:
            yield from row


class Node:
    def __init__(self, puzzle, parent=None):
        self.puzzle = puzzle
        self.parent = parent
        if self.parent:
            self.g = parent.g + 1
        else:
            self.g = 0

    def state(self) -> str:
        return str(self)

    def path(self):
        node, p = self, []
        while node:
            p.append(node)
            node = node.parent
        yield from reversed(p)

    def solved(self) -> bool:
        return self.puzzle.solved()

    def pretty_print(self) -> str:
        return self.puzzle.print_matrix()

    def h(self) -> int:
        return self.puzzle.manhattan()

    def f(self) -> int:
        return self.h() + self.g

    def all_moves(self) -> list:
        return self.puzzle.list_of_possible_moves()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.puzzle)

    def make_a_move(self, to: tuple) -> list:
        return self.puzzle.move(to)


class GameTree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def solve(self):
        queue = deque([Node(self.root)])
        seen = set()
        seen.add(queue[0].state())
        while queue:
            queue = deque(sorted(list(queue), key=lambda node: node.f()))
            node = queue.popleft()
            if node.solved():
                return node.path()

            for move in node.all_moves():
                moved = node.make_a_move(move)
                child = Node(Puzzle(moved), node)

                if child.state() not in seen:
                    queue.append(child)
                    seen.add(child.state())


def main():
    a = [[5, 4, 3], [0, 7, 2], [6, 1, 8]]
    c = Puzzle(a)
    d = GameTree(c)
    tic = perf_counter()
    p = d.solve()
    toc = perf_counter()
    step = 0
for i in p:
    print(i.pretty_print())
    step += 1
print(step)
print(toc-tic)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Description:

> The 15-puzzle (also called Gem Puzzle, Boss Puzzle, Game of Fifteen,
>   Mystic Square and many others) is a sliding puzzle that consists of a
>   frame of numbered square tiles in random order with one tile missing.
>   The puzzle also exists in other sizes, particularly the smaller
>   8-puzzle. If the size is 3×3 tiles, the puzzle is called the 8-puzzle
>   or 9-puzzle, and if 4×4 tiles, the puzzle is called the 15-puzzle or
>   16-puzzle named, respectively, for the number of tiles and the number
>   of spaces. The object of the puzzle is to place the tiles in order by
>   making sliding moves that use the empty space.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle

Comment: This is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com. You can flag for a moderator to perform the migration.

Comment: At a quick glance, your code seems reasonable. Why do you need it to perform faster? Using a (line-by-line) profiler. Or perhaps you should look into A* with an admissible heuristic.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq how to flag for a moderator to perform the migration?

Comment: There should be a link labelled "flag" above the comments section. Choose "in need of moderator intervention", then mention where you want to migrate to.

Comment: Your code seems reasonable. You might consider implementing other algorithms and compare the runtime w.r.t. that. Otherwise you might count the number of discovered states and compare it to other's solutions. You can have a look [this](https://github.com/biqar/puzzle-solver/tree/master/src/8-puzzle) for such comparisons.